# Помогите пожалуйста дописать sql запрос

Tags: java, mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT idPhone FROM log_sms  WHERE DateEvent >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 24 hour AND (select count(idPhone) from log_sms where  idPhone ) and idPhone   = ?
```

мне необходимо получить количество записей за  24 часа по конкретному idPhone и используя ResultSet посчитать их количество но он работает не правильно,   поскольку результат я получая не количество записей а idPhone

```
public static boolean isadminNamber(String phoneanmber) {
    try(Connection c = getConnection3()){
        String sql = "select count(idPhone) from log_sms where idPhone=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, phoneanmber);
        ResultSet rs =   ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
            int COUNTphonenanmber =   rs.getInt(1);

            if (COUNTphonenanmber >= 5){


                System.out.println("Client");


            }else {


                System.out.println("rrr");


            }
            return COUNTphonenanmber > 0;
```

Используя такой запрос я получаю количество записей и мой if работает

```
select count(idPhone) from log_sms where idPhone=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую по Ванговать.

```
Select count(*) from log_sms WHERE DateEvent >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 24 hour and idPhone=?
```

> используя ResultSet посчитать их количество

Их - количество айфонов или количество записей для каждого айфона?

Comment: Большое спасибо, количество записей для idPhone